# Problemas ao importar com LWJGL

Tags: java, importação, lwjgl

Olá, eu segui os passos desse **[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oDV9UXTk4Qo)**, e peguei o código de exemplo do [**site official**](https://www.lwjgl.org/guide).

Ao tentar importar diz que o **método é indefinido**:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que não deu certo porque faltaram alguns `import static`.

Experimente acrescentar esse trecho no início do arquivo `Main.java`:

```
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.*;
```

Comment: Funcionou, Obrigado.